# Matrix diagonalization. Can't see what I am doing wrong

Tags: matrices, diagonalization

I have to diagonolize a matrix A
\begin{bmatrix}0&-3&-1&1\\2&5&1&-1\\-2&-3&1&1\\2&3&1&1\end{bmatrix}

---

I do $det(A-λ)=0$ and I get $λ_{1}=1$, $λ_{2}=2$, $λ_{3}=2$, $λ_{4}=2$

So possible diagonal matrix looks like:
\begin{bmatrix}1&0&0&0\\0&2&0&0\\0&0&2&0\\0&0&0&2\end{bmatrix}

---

Then I look for eigenvectors for $λ=1$ and $λ=2$

I get:

For $λ=1$: $(1, -1, 1,-1)$

For $λ=2$: $(1, 0, 0, 2)$, $(0, 1, 0, 3)$, $(0, 0, 1, 1)$

I create matrix P made of eigenvectors (as columns):

\begin{bmatrix}1&1&0&0\\-1&0&1&0\\1&0&0&1\\-1&2&3&1\end{bmatrix}

---

And when checking if the diagonal matrix is correct by using formula:

$A=P^{-1}*D*P$

I don't get the correct answer :(

Can someone check my steps? I tried to do that a few times but still I am not getting the correct result.

Comment: Use http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=jordandecomposition+%7B%7B0,-3,-1,1%7D,%7B2,5,1,-1%7D,%7B-2,-3,1,1%7D,%7B2,3,1,1%7D%7D to think

Comment: It looks good to me, but is'nt $A=PDP^{-1}$ ?

Comment: Huh, I saw somewhere formula $A = P^{-1}AP$ and I just remembered that. I am gonna try once more with yours. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your computations are totally correct, but you made a tiny mistake in the order of the decomposition of $A$.
It has to be $A = PDP^{-1}$.

Just remind yourself, what if A was e.g. symmetric, since then one could find orthogonal transformations and there you immediately see, that the most right matrix has to contain the eigenvectors in a *horizontal* manner and the left matrix has to contain them *standing*.

Answer (score 2):

It seems you have not made any errors when computing the eigenvectors. I checked your results on the following matrix calculator: [is $P$ the correct transformation matrix?](https://matrixcalc.org/en/#%7B%7B1,1,0,0%7D,%7B-1,0,1,0%7D,%7B1,0,0,1%7D,%7B-1,2,3,1%7D%7D%5E%28-1%29%2A%7B%7B1,0,0,0%7D,%7B0,2,0,0%7D,%7B0,0,2,0%7D,%7B0,0,0,2%7D%7D%2A%7B%7B1,1,0,0%7D,%7B-1,0,1,0%7D,%7B1,0,0,1%7D,%7B-1,2,3,1%7D%7D)

Also as was pointed out, you must use the correct formula for going from one basis to the other. The matrix $P$ is a transformation from the eigenvectors basis to the canonical one, not the other way around, i.e. the formula is $A = P D P^{-1}$.

Comment: There are multiple bases to the eigenspaces... The eigenvectors in the question seem correct to me.

Comment: Indeed, the computation seems correct, I blindly used the wrong transformation formula as given by OP - corrected and given small argument why the formula should be the other way around (with the inverse on the right).